Sphinx: Bibtex bibliography that includes a link to download a file from my Web server
I have a Sphinx document using the sphinxcontrib.bibtex extension to create a bibliography in my project and it works great.  Now I would like to add a link to the bibliography entry to download a PDF.  Then the users can click to download to the cited paper from my documentation server, rather than hunting around in libraries and trying to access papers behind paywalls.
The workflow I (think I) want is:

user is in the docs and clicks on the citation link and is taken to the bibliography page.
In the bibliography entry, there is a link to the PDF that exists on my Web server.
User clicks the PDF link and the PDF is downloaded.

In Sphinx I found the download role for hand-creating the download in RST, and it copies the PDF to the server and creates the link.  But this does not seem compatible with the references.bib file.
I also found I can add the url={} field to the references.bib file.  This works great for urls to the outside world, but I can't make it point to a 'source' PDF file that is on my documentation server.  I would like to do something like  url = {:download:../bibliography/liou_1991.pdf} so when I build the docs the PDF is automatically copied to the server, but this doesn't work since the .bib file is processed as a LaTeX file, it doesn't recognize the :download: RST directive.
Is this type of link possible in Sphinx/bibtex?  Is there an alternative workflow to achieve this end?
